# Is it possible to make macros immediately followed by CJK chararacters work?

Tags: macros, cjk

For example, it reports error when I write (? stands for any CJK character)

```
\TeX??????
```

Since `\TeX??????` is not a defined command.

To make it right I have to insert a space or `{}` after `\TeX`.

But CJK characters are seldom (never for me) used as a part of a command name.

So I am wondering if it is possible to make a configure and make `\TeX??????` work.

I am using XeTeX with xeCJK package.

Comment: What engine are you using (pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX)?

Comment: You can change the catcodes of the CJK characters to be nonletter, then they will not be part of the command name.

Comment: I am using XeTeX with xeCJK package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can I change all CJK characters to be nonletter? And will it bring any bad side effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I ask `` \showthe\catcode`私 ``, XeTeX answers

```
> 11.
```

Thus yes, Japanese characters can be part of control sequence names. This is part of the initialization done by XeTeX. Changing the catcodes to 12 is neither recommended nor easy: you'd need to identify all Unicode blocks containing Japanese characters and do loops for changing the category codes. You could face unexpected issues, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho ProN}

\begin{document}

私は\TeXを使います

私は\TeX を使います

\end{document}
```

Just leave a space after `\TeX`.

The console output is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 私は\TeXを使います

?
```

The final output is

[image]

Blame Google Translate if the Japanese part doesn't make sense.

If you eventually decide for the loops, here they are:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho ProN}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \jiewuza_make_other:nn
 {
  \int_step_function:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \char_set_catcode_other:n
 }
\jiewuza_make_other:nn { "4E00 } { "9FEF } % CJK ideographs
\jiewuza_make_other:nn { "3041 } { "30FF } % Hiragana-Katakana
\jiewuza_make_other:nn { "31F0 } { "31FF } % Katakana additional
\jiewuza_make_other:nn { "32D0 } { "32FE } % Katakana circled
\jiewuza_make_other:nn { "FF01 } { "FFEE } % fullwidth-halfwidth
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

私は\TeXを使います

私は\TeX を使います

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`xetex -ini` reads `unicode-letters.def` at iniTeX state and catcode 11 for all unicode letters are set here (see line 45 of this file). You can re-declare all such letters with cactode 12 without any influence of functionality (exception: you cannot use such unicode letters in control sequences). You can do it by this code:

```
\begingroup
   \def\skipdefs #1\fi\fi{}
   \def\C#1 #2 #3 {}
   \def\L#1 #2 #3 {}
   \def\l#1 {\global \catcode"#1=12 }
   \expandafter\skipdefs \input unicode-letters.def
%\endgroup is in unicode-letters.def file
```

Comment: This file is no longer used by basic formats, although it is as you say still there. The data is slightly old, so there may be a few missed chars.